# LINQ to XML query returning a list of all child elements

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have got an XML document which looks something like this.

```
<Root>
<Info>....</Info>
<Info>....</Info>
<response>....</response>
<warning>....</warning>
<Info>....</Info>
</Root>
```

How can i write a LINQ to XML query so that it returns me an IEnumerable containing each child element, in this case all five child elements of , so that i could iterate over them.

The order of child elements is not definite, neither is number of times the may appear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [`Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) method to get all of the elements directly inside an `XElement`.
For example:

```
doc.Root.Elements()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the method `Elements() returns IEnumerable<XElement>`, is that what you are looking for?

Take a look in msdn though.. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx